# How to reorder map function in React

Tags: reactjs, loops, dictionary, for-loop

My data looks like this

```
data = [
  {
    "id": "27eb95f9",
    "title": "hello",
    "sort": 4
  },
  {
    "id": "367da510",
    "title": "bro",
    "sup-title": "",
    "sort": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "27eb95f9",
    "title": "how ",
    "sort": 3
  },
  {
    "id": "367da510",
    "title": "you doing",
    "sup-title": "",
    "sort": 1
  },
```

Now I want to use map funtion in React to show 'title' but I want the order to be according to "sort" in the object file. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use sort function, then map it! Please see below.
In the second exapmle you can use it to render your componenet as well.

Here can you read about sort method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": "27eb95f9",
    "title": "hello",
    "sort": 4
  },
  {
    "id": "367da510",
    "title": "bro",
    "sup-title": "",
    "sort": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "27eb95f9",
    "title": "how ",
    "sort": 3
  },
  {
    "id": "367da510",
    "title": "you doing",
    "sup-title": "",
    "sort": 1
  }];
  
const sortedTitles = data.sort((d1, d2)=>d1-d2).map((d)=>d.title);
console.table(sortedTitles);

render = data.sort((d1, d2)=>d1-d2).map((d)=>`<p>${d.title}</p>`).join("");
console.log(render);

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = render
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I believe they need to sort based on `(d1, d2) => d2.sort - d1.sort` since the sort value is in the "sort" property, right?

Comment: Yes. I should have changed the name of the property name and give something else rather than 'sort'.

Answer (score 0):

it may works, first JSON.parse(data) to have it as a object then

```
data.map(row => return {
   ...row, order : row.sort
})
```